Docker Container Crashes After Docker Prune: “could not access file ‘pg-qualstats’: No such file or directory”
I’m encountering an issue with my Docker container running PostgreSQL. The container crashes with the following error messages:
2024-08-19 15:58:33.235 UTC [1] FATAL:  could not access file "pg-qualstats": No such file or directory
2024-08-19 15:58:33.235 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is shut down

This is the link of pg-qualstats repo:
plugin link
Here are some details about my setup:
Docker versions:

client 26.1.3,
Server: Docker Engine - Community 26.1.4

Postgres version: 16.2
OS: Mac Sonoma Version 14.6.1 (23G93)
The pg-qualstats extension was manually installed and was working fine initially. However, after performing a docker system prune to clear some data, the issue started. I’ve tried restarting the container several times without success.
Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated!
